# XJC fails when backslash in schema import and bindings specified

Tags: uri, xjc, xjb

I want to generate Java classes from an XSD with xjc (version 2.3.0-b170531.0717)

Unfortunately the XSD imports another XSD given in a relative path with Windows path separators (backslash `\`), which is stated as an excluded character according to RFC-2396 in [xsi:schemaLocation backslash not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24406203/xsischemalocation-backslash-not-allowed)

When running just `xjc`, the schema compiles fine. But I want to specify some bindings with the command line parameter `-b bindings.xjb` and then the backslashes become a problem resulting in an failing the schema parse.

How can I get around this issue? I have tried using a catalog to resolve the paths but it seems to fail prior to the catalog use.

## Minimal working example

### a.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:b="b.xsd"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="b.xsd" schemaLocation=".\b.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

### b.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="b.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"/>
```

### c.xjb

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jaxb:version="2.0" />
```

### console output

```
> xjc a.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...

> xjc a.xsd -b c.xjb
parsing a schema...
[ERROR] Unable to parse ".\b.xsd" : File name is not an URI. Illegal character in path at index 1: .\b.xsd
  line 3 of a.xsd

Failed to parse a schema.
```

**EDIT:** With `xjc -verbose` I get the following StackTrace, stating it's a problem coming up from Java's `URI` class being standard conform and thus rejecting backslashes.

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 1: .\b.xsd
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2912)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3083)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3165)
    at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3124)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:598)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.reader.internalizer.AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.startElement(AbstractReferenceFinderImpl.java:81)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:351)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2706)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:601)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:531)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:887)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:823)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:639)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:380)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:260)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:291)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.ModelLoader.loadXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:344)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:147)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:102)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:339)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.run(Driver.java:206)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver._main(Driver.java:129)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver.access$000(Driver.java:67)
    at jdk.xml.bind@9.0.4/com.sun.tools.internal.xjc.Driver$1.run(Driver.java:88)
```

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I went with manually editing the schema files first to make them conform to the standard.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue today - it's still around. I also ended up also manipulating the schema files.